# XsltListViewWebpart error in quick edit mode (modern view)

Tags: list-view, custom-list, xslt-list-view-web-part, 2019, quick-edit

We have a site collection which has been migrated from SharePoint 2013 to 2019 recently and we have a list there. When I switch to quick edit mode in the list, I get the XsltListViewWebpart error.

Has anyone faced it?

Answer (score 0):

For some other reason, I've changed the master page from Oslo to Seattle (in the Design section of Site settings) - and that helped!